# Restart crontab @reboot rule without actual reboot

Tags: linux, cron

I'm using crontab with a `@reboot` entry which starts a script containing a endless while-loop that is processing the output of a `tail -F` command. Is there any way to stop the currently running script and restart the `@reboot` rule without a actual reboot? I'm running Debian 6.

Comment: Your question sounds very much like you want to use an init script instead of a crontab rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you know the name of the script (use pkill), or can find out its processid (ps aux, then kill -9). Then start it again using the same command as in crontab. If you want to detach the process from the session, [you can use nhup, or dtach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807688/how-to-detach-a-process-from-terminal-in-unix) or something similar.

Its pretty trivial. A better way to do this would be to write a init (or upstart or systemd) script, so you can just stop and start the service from there. This will depend on your distro, however.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is dated but wanted to add another answer in case anyone comes across it. The accepted answer is correct as it depends on your distro but here is how you can do it on Linux & Debian

You can also use the following commands to achieve this

```
sudo rm /var/run/crond.reboot 

sudo service cron restart
```

fyi you can see crontab logs like so:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Nice easy solution!